# Alternative to HandlerMethodArgumentResolver for each bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Let's say I have a standard spring MVC application where I have controllers that accepts form variables. These are basic forms that edit simple POJO beans.  User, Address, everyday stuff, nothing special.

I want to map the request parameters to my bean, so I don't have a bunch of @RequestParam  annotations in my controller method.  I do some research and I find the HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.  Looks like it would do the trick.

But do I need to make a HandlerMethodArgumentResolver class for *every* bean that I want to map?

I have a lot of them, and it seems like a lot of work.  My parameter names match with the variable names, so I could possibly JSON the form data on the front end,  send that via ajax call,  then marshal it in the controller. But is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you build a JSON with your fields on the front-end, you could use [`@RequestBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestbody) in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/something")
public void someMethod(@RequestBody SomeClass data) {
    // work with your data
}
```

`SomeClass` would be a common Java bean with all your fields:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private int field1;

    private String field2;

    private double field3;

    // getters & setters
}
```

For this to work, you'd need to configure a `HttpMessageConverter` that serializes and deserializes JSON. I think Spring does this automatically for you if it detects that the [Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is in the classpath.